# Pyglet import not found when using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

Ok so I'm trying to install pyglet using pip3 and I've used the command `pip3 install pyglet` and it works it's in my `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.9)` and I am using python 3.7. I have successfully imported things using pip before, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling... I'm not sure what the problem is the error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/plz.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyglet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyglet'
```

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and you installed `pyglet` in one Python but you run code with other Python. If you run code with `python3.7` then you can use `python3.7 -m pip install pyglet` to install it for `python3.7`. You can also check what you get with `pip3 -V` and you can alss check  if you don't have `pip3.7` specially for `python3.7`

Comment: It worked thank you so much!! Should I start importing everything with python3.7 -m pip install?

Comment: first check if you have `pip3.7` for this. If you don't have it then always uses `python3.7 -m pip install`. OR create own script `pip3.7` - you can also copy original `pip3` to `pip3.7` and edit it - it is Python's script - and set `shebang` with python3.7 (`#!/bin/env python3.7`)

Comment: Ok I have pip3 which is probably the issue... thank you!!